# When adding asterisk via :after in my css, my text link being pushed up in Angular app

Tags: css, angular, ng-class

I am trying to style a link in my Angular 2 app so as to show an asterisk next to the text when it's a view that contains required fields that are not yet filled in. I've got the functionality right, but the styling is proving more difficult than I expected.

In my view I am applying an additional "attention-needed" CSS class via Angular's "ngClass" when the attached function evaluates to false:

```
<div class="page-content-header-item" [class.selected]="isSection('general')" 
(click)="navigateTo('general')" [ngClass]="{'attention-needed': !hasGeneralInfo()}">General</div>
```

Then, I am trying to style the added asterisk like this:

```
.attention-needed {
    display: inline;
}

.attention-needed:after {
    content: "*";
    padding: 0 4px 0 5px;
}
```

The original base class for the link looks like this:

```
.app-page-view .page-content-header-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    align-self: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    min-width: 125px;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The functionality is all working as expected - in terms of the asterisk being applied at the right times.

However, when applied, the asterisk is showing up to the right of the text, as expected, but the entire text link is being pushed up. Not sure why this is happening, or how I can compensate for it. If I just add padding that proves problematic on the hover state, so I need some way of preventing the text from being pushed up when the asterisk is added via the "attention-needed" class.

Bottom line: all I want is to be able to add an asterisk to the right of the text link without adversely affecting the rest of the text link display. Too much to ask, css?

How can I do this and/or, what's causing the link to be bumped up to begin with?

Comment: _"Too much to ask, css?"_ CSS should be able to handle this fine, but the answer depends on the DOM structure that results after all the angular processing is complete. User your favorite browser's "inspect element" to see the ultimate relationship between the `.attention-needed` and `:after` elements; view the styles and _computed styles_ ... is one inline and the other inline-block? Do they have different line-heights? font-sizes? vertical-alignments?

Comment: I was being facetious. I know css can handle this. But it's, nevertheless, more complicated than it needs to be. If I want to change the text color with the added class - super easy. If I want to add an asterisk to the right of the text? Anything but. CSS is notoriously crazy and counter-intuitive at times. I look forward to continued styling evolution on the web. Good stuff is coming, beginning with flex and such.

Comment: Facetiousness aside :) I think the approach has to be to inspect and understand the DOM structure and relationship of the elements.  I place asterisks on required fields using `:before` or `:after` and it's super easy, but my structure is simple: `<span><label for="id">text</label> <input ...></span>`